# RequireJS jQuery plugin shim not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to get a jQuery plugin working properly with RequireJS, when using jQuery in the noconflict/noglobal state to force all modules to indicate whether they require jQuery. However, for non-AMD-friendly plugins, the `shim` config seems to not be working. Namely, if a jQuery plugin is defined with a wrapper like:

```
(function($) {
  $.extend($.myPlugin, { myPlugin: { version:'0.0.1'} });
})(jQuery);
```

Then the following RequireJS configuration isn't working:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min', 'jquery-min'],
  },
  map: {
    '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-noglobal' }, // Force all modules to use the non-global jQuery...
    'jquery-noglobal': { 'jquery': 'jquery' } // ...except the wrapper module itself, which  needs the real one.
  },
  shim: {
    'sadPlugin': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
});
```

`jquery-noglobal.js`:

```
define(['jquery'], function(jq) {
  return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

The error that fires when the plugin code runs is: "can't call `extend` on `undefined`", meaning `jQuery` was never set at the outer level, so `$` is undefined inside the self-executing function. I put breakpoints outside the plugin self-executing function, and inside to verify that.

I'm guessing part of the problem is capitalization; the module was written to expect `jQuery` (camelCase), while the AMD module name is `jquery` (lower case). Is there any way in the `shim` config to specify what the injected requirements' variable names should be?

I've also tried adding a `sadPlugin: {'jquery':'jquery'}` entry to the `map` hash, hoping to make `shim` give that module the global jQuery instead of the non-global one, but still jQuery/$ aren't defined by the time the function gets called.

**EDIT:** Found one kludge that does answer part of the problem: according to the comment found [here](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim/issues/6#issuecomment-12049966), the `deps` of a `shim` need to be the *full file path* of the script to load, and cannot be an alias from the `paths` configuration.

So, since my CDN-fallback file of jQuery is `jquery-min.js`, if I do:

```
shim: {
  'sadPlugin': {
    deps: ['jquery-min']
  }
}
```

The plugin works! However, since the "real" jQuery is now being used, it pollutes the global namespace, and the `$` variable is then available without `require()`ing it, so defeats the whole purpose of the `noglobal` wrapper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
return jQuery.noConflict( true );
```

instead of

```
return jq.noConflict( true );
```

So, as local variable inside requirejs, your plugins can use the variable jQuery for the parameter $

```
(function($) {$.extend($.myPlugin, { myPlugin: { version:'0.0.1'} });})(jQuery);
```

The config that work for me is:

-- main.js

-- jquery-private.js

In main.js file:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
  },
  map: {
    '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },
    'jquery-private': { 'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' }

  },
  shim: {
    myplugins: ['jquery']
  }
});
```

In jquery-private.js file:

```
define(['jquery'], function () {
  jQuery = $.noConflict(true);
  return jQuery;
});
```